# '(match_start1)...(match_start2)...(match_end)' find the shortest string match

Tags: python, regex

I've read over this post [How do I find the shortest overlapping match using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148700/how-do-i-find-the-shortest-overlapping-match-using-regular-expressions) but the answer there doesn't work for my case.

I was looking for pattern `'\D\d{2,5}?.+?CA.??[ \-\.\_]*(?:\d{5})?', 
the string is '6785 56767at435 hjfioej st. CA.    94827ifojwnf 93842'`

Both `'t435 hjfioej st. CA.    94827'` and `' 56767at435 hjfioej st. CA.    94827'` should match, but the procedure given in the above post is not giving the minimum match.

Please help.

Comment: Please add all the matches YOU think you should be getting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Both 't435 hjfioej st. CA. 94827' and ' 56767at435 hjfioej st. CA. 94827' should match

Comment: Ah, I forgot the (?=   ) part, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.findall('(?=(\D\d{2,5}?.+?CA.?[ -._]*(?:\d{5})?))','6785 56767at435 hjfioej st. CA. 94827ifojwnf 93842')
```

So this will do the trick, then output the one of the minimum length.