# Mark the shortest overlapping match using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148700/how-do-i-find-the-shortest-overlapping-match-using-regular-expressions) shows how to find the **shortest overlapping match** using regex. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554619/2870222) shows how to get the shortest match, but I am struggling with how to **locate** the shortest match and **mark** its position, or **substitute** it with another string.

So in the given pattern,

```
A|B|A|F|B|C|D|E|F|G
```

and the pattern I want to locate is:

```
my_pattern = 'A.*?B.*?C'
```

How can I identify the shortest match and mark it in the original given pattern like below?

```
A|B|[A|F|B|C]|D|E|F|G
```

or substitute:

```
A|B|AAA|F|BBB|CCC|D|E|F|G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554619/2867928) with `re.sub` :

```
>>> p=re.findall(r'(?=(A.*?B.*?C))',s)
>>> re.sub(r'({})'.format(re.escape(min(p, key=len))),r'[\1]',s,re.DOTALL)
'A|B|[A|F|B|C]|D|E|F|G'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use lookahead between `A` and `B` and then `B` and `C` like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'A(?:(?![AC]).)*B(?:(?![AB]).)*C')
test_str = u"A|B|A|F|B|C|D|E|F|G"
result = re.sub(p, u"[$0]", test_str)
# A|B|[A|F|B|C]|D|E|F|G

test_str = u"A|B|C|F|B|C|D|E|F|G"
result = re.sub(p, u"[$0]", test_str)
# [A|B|C]|F|B|C|D|E|F|G
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC3wV5/2)

Comment: Do note that `#` is comment in python and not `//`

Comment: what about  `A|B|F|B|C|A|D|B|C|F|G` ? or another strings that has many combinations of `ABC` and other letters?  and can you pleas explain how this pattern will match the **minimum**?

Answer (score 1):

```
(A[^A]*?B[^B]*?C)
```

You can use this simple regex.Replace by `[\1]`.

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/34)

`x="A|B|A|F|B|C|D|A|B|C"`
`print re.sub("("+re.escape(min(re.findall(r"(A[^A]*?B[^B]*?C)",x),key=len))+")",r"[\1]",x)`

Comment: Note that `[^A]*` may match `BC`.

Comment: can you try `A|B|C|F|B|C|D|E|F|G` ? it must match `A|B|C`!! does it?

Comment: @Kasra it will match `A|B|C`

Comment: so see https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/36 , your answer an anubhava 's answer are not the correct answer for this question! as you may know  Tim Pietzcker is the top regex answerers!!! and he have gave that answer!  you must be note that you need to match the minimum match so in a string that has a lot of combination in form `A.*?B.*?C`  you want the minimum and its impossible to find that with one line regex!!!! also see this https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/37

Comment: @Kasra edited.Now it will give correct answer.This is more efficient as your regex will find 2 matches if input is `A|A|B|B|C|C|F|K|D|E|F|G` and then find `minimumu` where as this will straightaway find the correct one :)